Grub2 every if statement results in true
I'm currently changing my grub2 menu.
I've got this if statement for testing purposes:
set var1 = "foo"
if[ "${var1}" = "bar"]; then
    default=2
fi

No matter what is written in the var1, the if statement always result in true.
set model = "foo"
if[ "${model}" = "bar"]; then
    default=2
else
    default=0
fi

If I also add an else to it, it will execute both lines.
Is it even possible to check the name of an variable in grub2?

Have you tried with spaces around the [ and ]? And if grub is anything like bash, you may need to remove the spaces around the assignment operator in the first line, set var1="foo".

Yeah, the missing spaces were the problem... and also the set var1="foo", it was some dummy code tho.

Sure, but dummy code should of course also be reproducible, so match as exact as possible; always the tricky part of creating dummy code for a small example.

I'll copy the comment to an answer for clarity, now that it has solved the problem (I wasn't sure, since I had no quick way to test it).

Make sure there are spaces around the test operators [ and ].
Also remove the spaces around the assignment operator in set var1 = "foo".
Thus:
set var1="foo"
if [ "${var1}" = "bar" ] ; then
    default=2
fi

(I think the space after the ] is not necessary, but it won't hurt either.)

Presumably, instead of creating a syntax error, Grub just skips over that error to make sure it doesn't crash; although that seems odd (bad) practice. Or, in the context of your actual problem, it may stop and somehow the a result that matches your description of the comparison always evaluating to true.

Your explanation makes sense, given that if[ and then are not valid commands and their exit statuses are ignored.  So the default=2 line is run conditionally.  It's similar to running a shell without -e, except that probably then and fi are parsed as commands rather than keywords in GRUB.
